# Dot product along third axis

Tags: python, numpy, tensor, dot-product

I'm trying to take a tensor dot product in numpy using `tensordot`, but I'm not sure how I should reshape my arrays to achieve my computation. (I'm still new to the mathematics of tensors, in general.)

I have

```
arr = np.array([[[1, 1, 1],
                [0, 0, 0],
                [2, 2, 2]],

               [[0, 0, 0],
                [4, 4, 4],
                [0, 0, 0]]])

w = [1, 1, 1]
```

And I want to take a dot product along `axis=2`, such that I have the matrix

```
array([[3, 0, 6],
       [0, 12, 0]])
```

What's the proper numpy syntax for this? `np.tensordot(arr, [1, 1, 1], axes=2)` seems to raise a `ValueError`.

Comment: A better sample might be with something like `w = [1,2,3]`, just to have some variety there.

Comment: I set `w = [1,1,1]` to make it obvious that we're just trying to add up the elements inside each of the inner dimensions.

Comment: If you are not scaling as with `w = [1,1,1]`, then it's just adding elements along `axis=2` in `arr`. So, with that specific `w`, you don't really need any dot product and could just sum elements of `arr` along `axis=2`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The reduction is along `axis=2` for `arr` and `axis=0` for `w`. Thus, with [`np.tensordot`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html), the solution would be -

```
np.tensordot(arr,w,axes=([2],[0]))
```

Alternatively, one can also use [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
np.einsum('ijk,k->ij',arr,w)
```

[`np.matmul`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) also works

```
np.matmul(arr, w)
```

Runtime test -

```
In [52]: arr = np.random.rand(200,300,300)

In [53]: w = np.random.rand(300)

In [54]: %timeit np.tensordot(arr,w,axes=([2],[0]))
100 loops, best of 3: 8.75 ms per loop

In [55]: %timeit np.einsum('ijk,k->ij',arr,w)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.78 ms per loop

In [56]: %timeit np.matmul(arr, w)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.72 ms per loop
```

hlin117 tested on Macbook Pro OS X El Capitan, numpy version 1.10.4.

Comment: ...and if you have Python 3.5, simply `arr @ w` (or `np.matmul(arr, w)` in earlier versions) ;-)

Comment: @ajcr Been hearing about that feature a lot lately, still couldn't get my hands on it yet! Gotta try it soon.

Comment: @ajcr That `np.matmul(arr, w)`could be a good alternative solution! Post it maybe as a separate answer?

Comment: Thanks for the timings! Neat to see how much faster tensordot is.

Comment: nice rundown of the options

Answer (score 3):

Using `.dot` works just fine for me:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([[[1, 1, 1],
                     [0, 0, 0],
                     [2, 2, 2]],

                    [[0, 0, 0],
                     [4, 4, 4],
                     [0, 0, 0]]])
>>> arr.dot([1, 1, 1])
array([[ 3,  0,  6],
       [ 0, 12,  0]])
```

Although interestingly is slower than all the other suggestions